# How do you add context menu seperator to Windows7/8 using reg

Tags: windows, registry, regedit

So I have added two context menu items for my application to be displayed when user right clicks a folder as follows:

```
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\SongKong.Match /ve /t REG_SZ /d Match with SongKong /f 
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\SongKong.Match\Command /ve /t REG_SZ /d \"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\SongKong64.exe\" -g -m \"%1\" /f 
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates /ve /t REG_SZ /d Delete duplicates with SongKong /f 
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates\Command /ve /t REG_SZ /d \"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\SongKong64.exe\" -g -d \"%1\" /f
```

But I would like to separate them from entries above and below with a separator (is this the correct terminology) how can that be done please.

Comment: That requires a shell extension, IContextMenu interface.  That would make it a programming question, ask for advice at superuser.com

Comment: @HansPassant thx, but if its a programming question then isn't it a stack overflow question.

Comment: Can it not been done with REG, my codebase is actually Java so having to use IContextMenu would be problematic.